# Determine bigger number and divide

Tags: javascript, math

Ok, I don't know how to put this in short.

This is my code:

```
var ratio, input={w:100,h:50};
if(input.w <= input.h) ratio = input.h / input.w;
else                   ratio = input.w / input.h;
```

**Question:**
Is there faster, better, "less code needed" way to calculate `ratio` ? Than if/else statements.

Thanks!

Comment: You *could* also sort first: `var sorted = [input.w, input.h].sort(), ratio = sorted[1] / sorted[0]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the ternary conditional operator. Syntax:

```
condition ? (statement if true) : (statement if false);
```

In your case:

```
ratio = (input.w <= input.h) ? (input.h/input.w) : (input.w/input.h);
```

EDIT:

This isn't faster than your solution, just faster to write. I would advise against using:

```
var ratio = Math.Max(input.w, input.h) / Math.Min(input.w, input.h)
```

That will compare the numbers twice (once in Math.Max, once in Math.Min) and would be slower.

Comment: In current version of chrome, the accepted solution not only is the poor performance wise, it's also less legible. while the advise to go against the max min is currently in chrome 28 the fastest.

Answer (score 7):

```
var ratio = Math.max(input.w, input.h) / Math.min(input.w, input.h)
```

another [maybe more efficient]:

```
var ratio = Math.max(input.w / input.h, 1 / input.w / input.h);
```

even more efficient than ternary :

```
var ratio = w / h ;
ratio = ratio > 1 && ratio || 1/ratio
```

Comment: Wouldn't this compare the numbers twice, as opposed to once?

Comment: ... and make two function calls to do so.

Comment: Also note that it will throw a syntax error... the methods are `max` and `min` (lower-case)

Comment: -1 I think this is less efficient and also less readable than using the ternary operator.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - Actually, this is nearly twice as fast as the ternary version! (On Firefox 8 at least): http://jsperf.com/max-min-vs-ternary

Comment: the questing doesnt ask for efficiency, if you want efficiency you would like something:
ratio = Math.max(input.h/input.w, 1/input.h/input.w);

Comment: Right, it is like (input.w > input.h? input.w:input.h)/(input.w>input.h?input.h:input.w)

Comment: The ternary is faster in Chrome. I ran the test you posted. And it makes sense to me.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - Yeah, that makes sense to me too! I wasn't expecting the result I saw in Firefox.

Comment: amazing how in new version of chrome this gets optimized a lot, making Min Max the Fastest :D

Answer (score 2):

Smaller not necessarily faster:

```
var ratio, input = {w:100, h:50};
ratio = input.w <= input.h ? input.h / input.w : input.w / input.h;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
ratio = Math.max(input.w, input.h) / Math.min(input.w, input.h)
```

Comment: Isn't this less efficient, since it compares the numbers twice?

Comment: Yes that's true, but personally (outside of something intensive like an animation) I wouldn't worry about a few microseconds

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary operator:

```
var ratio = (input.w <= input.h ? (input.h / input.w) : (input.w / input.h));
```